# KiCad create and understand netlist

Tags: kicad

I made a schematic in KiCad with hierarchical layout. I'd like to check if the busses are connected the way I want. In this context I often read something about the netlist. 
So my question is, how do I generate a netlist and what does it tell me about the connections?

Answer (score 1):

To generate a netlist, open Eeschema and click on the netlist button
[image: Netlist Button] in the toolbar.

This will open the netlist dialog:
[image]

You want to generate the default pcbnew format (Kicad's internal netlist format).

Then open the resulting file in a text editor.  You will find a section that starts with `(nets`

[image: Netlist text file]

In this file, notice first that each `(Net` is listed with a `(code)` and a `(name)`.  After this, each pin for each component is listed that is connected to the named net.  To check whether your bus connections are correct, you should find the two pins you want to connect and verify that they are in the same net.

You can also do this using pcbnew after you have imported the netlist and done some initial layout.  But the text-file method described above should work for you before you get to that step.

Comment: Okay thanks. I know now that my busses are not connectet. Do you know how I connect two buses on different hierarchical sheets? I tried to put labels on it but it doesn't work. I've read here: http://docs.kicad-pcb.org/stable/en/eeschema.html#connections-buses but i don't get where I have to connect the busses.

Comment: You can look here (https://forum.kicad.info/t/sending-bus-between-sheets/9061) for a couple details on that question.  If the answer helped, please mark it accepted with the check next to it.